# How to write the underscore dash in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I would like to write the following attached letter

[image]

I have tried $Hu_(x,\theta)$  but it is not printing what I want. Thank you

Comment: Use `$Hu\_(x, \theta)$`.

Comment: @Thruston can we increase the length of the dash ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
The underscore character shape is set by the font designer: $Hu\_(x,\theta)$

\medskip\noindent
But you can draw your own rules: $Hu \hbox to 3em{\thinspace\hrulefill\thinspace}(x,\theta)$

\medskip\noindent
Possibly you want it like this: $\hbox to 4em{Hu\thinspace\hrulefill\thinspace}(x,\theta)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

- My apologies for using plain TeX `\hbox` -- you can do the same with LaTeX `\makebox` but I can never remember the syntax.